# Where clause based on value from function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server function that combines some data for output for an address

```
dbo.pt_FormatAddress(
    Permit_Address.Permit_No,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Fraction,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Direction,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Address,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Unit,
    Permit_Address.Permit_CityName,
    0,
    0,
    0
) as ADR
```

This will produce a result like:

```
400 BELL STREET, SOMECITY
```

I would like to do something like this in the `WHERE` Clause:

```
WHERE ADR LIKE '%400 BELL STREET%'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical order of query processing phases is:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

So you don't have access the aliases you make in `SELECT` in your `WHERE` clause

Use this:

```
WHERE
dbo.pt_FormatAddress(
    Permit_Address.Permit_No,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Fraction,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Direction,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Address,
    Permit_Address.Permit_Unit,
    Permit_Address.Permit_CityName,
    0,
    0,
    0
) LIKE '%400 BELL STREET%'
```

Also you have an option to put your main query in a `CTE` and use the alias from that.

Something like this:

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT dbo.pt_FormatAddress(
        Permit_Address.Permit_No,
        Permit_Address.Permit_Fraction,
        Permit_Address.Permit_Direction,
        Permit_Address.Permit_Address,
        Permit_Address.Permit_Unit,
        Permit_Address.Permit_CityName,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ) as ADR
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM C
WHERE ADR LIKE '%400 BELL STREET%'
```

[LOGICAL QUERY PROCESSING](http://www.sqlabout.com/logical-query-processing/)

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you!  I was thinking I was going to have to create a VIEW and then use the view.